# java (jvm) gc logs, что это значит?

Tags: java, jvm, сборщик-мусора

Подскажите, что значит лог gc в java:

> 2017-10-21T01:58:13.453+0300: 163918.493: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2017-10-21T01:58:13.453+0300: 163918.493: [ParNew (0: promotion failure size = 3)
>     (1: promotion failure size = 3)  (2: promotion failure size = 4)  (3: promotion failure size = 3)  (4: promotion failure size = 3)  (5: promotion 
>   failure size = 3)  (6: promotion failure size = 1310722)  (7: promotion failure size = 3)  (8: promotion failure size = 7)  (9: promotion failure si
>   ze = 3)  (promotion failed): 552960K->552960K(552960K), 0.3093364 secs]2017-10-21T01:58:13.763+0300: 163918.802: [CMS2017-10-21T01:58:21.834+0300: 1
>   63926.874: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 8.883/9.338 secs] [Times: user=18.83 sys=0.23, real=9.33 secs] 
>    (concurrent mode failure): 7389105K->3921591K(9871360K), 17.0332925 secs] 7942062K->3921591K(10424320K), [Metaspace: 49844K->49844K(1095680K)], 17.3436247 secs] [Times: user=19.15 sys=0.00, real=17.35 secs] 
>   Heap after GC invocations=157710 (full 283):
>    par new generation   total 552960K, used 0K [0x0000000540000000, 0x0000000565800000, 0x0000000565800000)
>     eden space 491520K,   0% used [0x0000000540000000, 0x0000000540000000, 0x000000055e000000)
>     from space 61440K,   0% used [0x000000055e000000, 0x000000055e000000, 0x0000000561c00000)
>     to   space 61440K,   0% used [0x0000000561c00000, 0x0000000561c00000, 0x0000000565800000)
>    concurrent mark-sweep generation total 9871360K, used 3921591K [0x0000000565800000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
>    Metaspace       used 49844K, capacity 51634K, committed 51832K, reserved 1095680K
>     class space    used 6118K, capacity 6514K, committed 6568K, reserved 1048576K
>   }

```
1. [ParNew (0: promotion failure size = 3)
  (1: promotion failure size = 3)  (2: promotion failure size = 4)  (3: promotion failure size = 3)  (4: promotion failure size = 3)  (5: promotion 
failure size = 3)  (6: promotion failure size = 1310722)  (7: promotion failure size = 3)  (8: promotion failure size = 7)  (9: promotion failure si
ze = 3)  (promotion failed)
```

Что значит `0: .., 1: ..., 2: ..., ... 9:` — что это за 9 разделов?

`2. concurrent mode failure` - почему?

Итог - фриз на 17 секунд.

Comment: *The inability to complete a collection concurrently is referred to as concurrent mode failure and indicates the need to adjust the CMS collector parameters* - приложение успело заполнить хип быстрее, чем CMS разгрести в параллель, поэтому CMS принудительно остановил виртуальную машину.

Comment: Это не 9 разделов, это 9 потоков сборщика мусора.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev - спасибо, с одним вопросом покончено!

Comment: @etki "приложение успело заполнить хип быстрее, чем CMS разгрести в параллель" - это как бы общий ответ почему GC STW вообще произошёл, он по другой причине и не происходит, мне интересно именно этот кейс почему произошёл...

(concurrent mode failure): 7389105K->3921591K(9871360K)
всего 10Gb heap, занято 7,3? самый большой promotion failure size 1,3 Мб!!! как же так не хватило 2,7 Гб для 1,3 Мб?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev если не сложно... все эти 9 потоков пытались из ParNew перенести данные??? (из ParNew насколько я понимаю конкурентно вообще не копируются данные, все кто выжил тупо копируются либо в Survivour либо в OldGen)

Comment: Всё верно, не нашли место в tenured.

Comment: _как же так не хватило 2,7 Гб для 1,3 Мб_ Предполагаю, что фрагментация старого поколения была настолько высокая, что не было возможности найти подходящую непрерывную область памяти для записи блока данных. Могу быть неправ.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev получается мне не повезло, одновременно произошло переполнение tenured (там 61 Мб у меня, а не влезло 1,3Мб) + при этом переполнилось и OldGen и ещё и он был сильно дефрагментирован так, что (ParNew + Tenured) ~= 600 Мб не влез в 2,7 Гб?